# Unable to retrieve rendering parameter in controller

Tags: presentation

I have a legacy MVC action I'm trying to enhance for some limited number of cases.  The solution I'm working on uses rendering parameters to impact the behavior of the control.  To demonstrate the concept, I began with adding parameters to one of the rendering in question.  Note: I'd prefer to do this without a rendering template, opting instead for the generic "additional parameters" fields on the rendering: 
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPhWs.png]

In my controller action, I attempt to read those parameters:

```
string testValue = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["TestValue"];
if (!testValue.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
  // Do some things with the value
}
```

However, according the the debugger, `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters` is an empty collection in the controller-action.

Is it required that I use a Rendering parameters template?  Is there some setting I need to touch to pass generic rendering params to the context?

Updated with a bit more investigation based on the comments:

In `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.` I get an ID I can-not match (that changes on subsequent executions).  The same context lists the deviceID and LayoutID as `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`, which doesn't seem correct.
I checked renderings using `Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false)`, and it did contain the rendering I expected.

In my case, I know the control will only be included once, so I was able to resolve the correct settings looking for the ID of the rendering

```
ID contentDetailRenderingId = new ID("{B852FF27-F4E5-4E70-85B7-CB60A860F59F}");
RenderingReference[] renderings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false);
RenderingReference rendering = renderings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.RenderingID == contentDetailRenderingId);
```

However, I'd have greatly preferred to match to something from the context rather than a constant-guid.
I suspect my specific issue may have to do with device resolution, and I haven't been able to resolve that yet.  That said, I'm still looking for anything in the `RenderingContext` I can use to properly ID the rendering configuration in the presentation details.

Comment: If you debug it, is the Rendering ID the rendering you expect. This is one of the simplest things to do in Sitecore. Something simple must be a little off.

Comment: It's not a requirement to use the Rendering Parameters template, but I would say it's a better practice to do so, since it's easier for the Content Editor.  If you leave it like it is, you could suffer from situations where a content editor miss-types the name of a parameter, and then the expected functionality doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Make sure you've published your content and that workflow isn't blocking the item from publishing.  Rendering Parameters are saved to the Rendering information on your Context Item and not to the Datasource Item, so make sure your page is published.

Comment: Your first screenshot. Is that from the properties of the rendering in presentation details, or is that from the rendering definition item?

Comment: Presentation details (Control Properties from the Device Editor from the Layout Details modal).

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine. Please check below points.
- Remove custom patch if any.
- Check the method you are debugging is tagged with correct attribute like [HTTP GET/Post].
- Debug and check the objects under Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation, it will give you entire detail about your page presentation.

Comment: We had a similar problem, I added a new rendering parameter, but it wasn't coming through as part of the rendering parameter values in my code through Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters. I set the standard value for it, and made sure it was set on the Presentation details. I also did a full site republish. Because I set the standard value, the value was ticked by default. When I unticked, published, then ticked and published again it worked.